# Mixed site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, modern-team-site

One our teams asked for a new, mixed type of site collection that is

1. outside from /sites (so mycompany.sharepoint.com/requestedsitecollecion
2. and able to host both classic and modern sites like

> ```
>  mycompany.sharepoint.com/requestedsitecollecion/ClassicSite
>  mycompany.sharepoint.com/requestedsitecollecion/ModernSite
> ```

Is any of this even possible? According to them it should be, but I found only options to put site collections under /sites or /teams, and I didn't find any templates with such a mixed funcionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In O365 you are restrained from having your own site locations and you are stuck with /sites/ due to the multi tenant setup.

You can have a site under /sites/requestedsitecollecion/ and create 2 subsites and set them to classic or modern

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the future options (mixed subsites), does it matter what template do I chose for the site collection?

Answer (score 1):

As SPO limitation you cant have the custom Managed Path so best option is create a site collections, 1 with modern team site and 2nd with classic team site. Name both site collection url in a way so that you can understand it.

for example: `http://url/sites/Mod_requestedurl` or something and `http://url/sites/Clas_requestedurl`

Msft also recommended approach always create site collections rather Subsites. Also i am sure you cant create subsite with modern team site template.

> If you provision a sub site under the root site of a "modern" site
>   collection, sub sites will use "classic" templates. There are
>   currently no "modern" sub site templates available. Y

[Provisioning "modern" team sites programmatically](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-provisioning-sites)

[Create a team site in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-team-site-in-sharepoint-online-ef10c1e7-15f3-42a3-98aa-b5972711777d)